# How to use an .mdb file without installing MS Access?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I have a database named `Sample.mdb` and i **Created required columns**   , i want to use it in my java application,

Is it possible to use the database without installing `MS Access Software` it my system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc).

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggetions,,,It really worked and ver good explanations...Thanks gord

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) project, is simple and stable.

Comment: Thanks for you time....i just used http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html...